# How to find when an object value changes in IE

Tags: javascript, debugging, tinymce

I'm working on a big application that has no documentation or comments. There is a difference in behavior between IE and Firefox and Chrome. In order to debug it I have to find a place where a property is being changed (tinymce.editors.length , I need to find out where a tinymce editor is being created, because it is created in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome). As of now the only option seems to be to blindly put breakpoints around all scripts, but there are tens of thousands of lines, so any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Use ctrl-f (find) on the source code and hope that the string 'tinymce.editors.length' appears there. Or is it minified code? You can also step through the entire program frm the start i guess.

Comment: @Silly the variable does not appear in the code, it is not changed by the script itself, it's a call to an external library (google tinymce), and it contains information about how many editors were created, the problem is I can not find where they are created even after setting breakpoints around all the calls to the init functions.

Comment: Do you have the link to tinymce? Since that path should appear somewhere as a string then, either in the code itsself or in some config file. Or some other string you can identify tinymce with? Else you're stuck with watching the network tab and the object watches inside debugger.

Comment: `because it is created in IE but not in IE`

Answer (score 2):

When you load the script for TinyMCE it will create a global object in the browser named `tinymce`.  The sheer act of loading the script creates this object.

Within the `tinymce` object is an array named `editors`.  The TinyMCE editor uses this array to keep track of all the editor instances on the web page. Each time you initialize an instance of TinyMCE its added to the array and each time you remove an instance of TinyMCE its removed from the array.  You should never need to manipulate the `tinymce.editors` array yourself.

The most common way to initialize an instance of TinyMCE is via the `init()` function.  A very simple example of that can be found here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/first-steps/#step2initializetinymceaspartofawebform

...and the API itself is documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#init

I would review the source code of the application looking for use of the `init()` method to determine where in your code the editor is getting instantiated.

Comment: I set up a breakpoint at each init, the editors.length seems to not change even after exiting them (when seen from variable watch). However, when I type "tinymvc.editors.length;" in the IE console after the document fully loads, it clearly states there are 4. Do you know if editors are added immediately after the init, or are they added at some other point in the future?

Comment: The `init()` calls are asynchronous so if you check the length immediately after calling `init()` I would not be surprised if its not yet registered in the array.